# Бронирование места при view.invisible

Tags: activity, android, java

*Когда я скрываю элемент с помощью view.invisible, то для него бронируется место, и вместо него отображается белый фон.* **Как сделать так, что скрытии элемента его как-будто не было, а место ему бронировалось только при вызове его отображения?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
View.GONE;
```

Comment: @Gorets краткость сестра таланта...